# aws-sdk: crash after updating from angular5 to angular6

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, typescript, aws-sdk

I just updated to Angular 6.0 from Angular 5.2, my code now break with this error:

```
core.js:1601 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: global is 
not defined
ReferenceError: global is not defined
at Object../node_modules/buffer/index.js (index.js:43)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
at Object../node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/browserHashUtils.js 
(browserHashUtils.js:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
at Object../node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/browserHmac.js (browserHmac.js:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
at Object../node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/browserCryptoLib.js 
(browserCryptoLib.js:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
at Object../node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/browser_loader.js (browser_loader.js:4)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
at Object../node_modules/buffer/index.js (index.js:43)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
at Object../node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/browserHashUtils.js 
(browserHashUtils.js:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
at Object../node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/browserHmac.js (browserHmac.js:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
at Object../node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/browserCryptoLib.js 
(browserCryptoLib.js:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
at Object../node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/browser_loader.js (browser_loader.js:4)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
```

anybody knows the problem?
I have tried ng update but seems like aws-sdk-js doesn’t provide the schematics for updating

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Add following to polyfills.ts

```
// aws-sdk requires global to exist
(window as any).global = window;
```

Answer (score 15):

There is a workaround until this issue is resolved,

try adding in your index.html head tag the following

```
<script>
  if (global === undefined) {
    var global = window;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: also when your framework doesn't have a polyfills.ts file ember-cli: 3.15.2

Answer (score 3):

Accodring to this documentation (and tested by me): https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/media/angular_guide

you only need to add this line to your polyfills.ts file, at the top:

```
(window as any).global = window;
```

This should fix it and is the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

> ReferenceError: global is not defined

## Fix

From https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9920 : `Node shims have been removed in 6.0`

Solution: The code that is breaking is the problem. At least that is the stance from angular. E.g. report to aws-sdk etc.